# Issue with Spark dataframe loading timestamp data to hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I am trying to load a dataframe to hive table. But it is adding additional 30 minutes to the table.
I have tried the below

```
from pyspark import SparkContext,HiveContext

sc = SparkContext()

hive_context = HiveContext(sc)


df_load.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("default.DATA_LOAD")
```

**the df_load has a column "currenthour" with value "2020-09-01 09:00:00". But in the table, it is loaded as "2020-09-01 09:30:00".**

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Its a common issue with Timestamp datatype because of the timezone.
Refer this:

[Spark SQL to Hive table - Datetime Field Hours Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433582/spark-sql-to-hive-table-datetime-field-hours-bug)